# How to skip label/numbering of single subfloats?

Tags: numbering, subfloats

I am trying to figure out how to skip the numbering of some subfloats in a figure. I noticed that if I pass no arguments to `subfloat`, no label/numbering is printed, but the image is still counted for the numbering. For instance, in the following example, I need just captions for figs A and B, but they come up as (b) and (e) due to their relative instanciation. How to overcome this?
Thanks, Jorge.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[!t]
    \fbox{\noindent\begin{minipage}[b][18cm]{0.45\linewidth}
        \subfloat{\includegraphics[height=8cm,width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image}}
        \vfill
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=8cm,width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
    \end{minipage}}%
    \hfill
    \fbox{\noindent\begin{minipage}[b][18cm]{0.45\linewidth}
        \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image}}
        \vfill
        \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image}}
        \vfill
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
    \end{minipage}}%
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: simple not use `subfloat` where you not needed.

Comment: @Zarko: Sorry, I did not see your comment -- apparently we had the same idea at (almost) the same time

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, i'm glad that you elaborate this idea. at this time i haven't more time as for short comment :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just omit the `\subfloat` macro and use only the `\includegraphics` macro for the figures that should not be numbered or obtain a caption description.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!t]
    \fbox{\noindent\begin{minipage}[b][18cm]{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[height=8cm,width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image}
        \vfill
        %\includegraphics[height=8cm,width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=8cm,width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
    \end{minipage}}%
    \hfill
    \fbox{\noindent\begin{minipage}[b][18cm]{0.45\linewidth}

        \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image}
        \vfill
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image}
        \vfill
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
    \end{minipage}}%
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]